# How to create recursion for vector addition?

Tags: c, recursion

I need help with this code problem, if anyone had a similar problem it would help me a lot.
It is necessary to write a program that loads a natural number n, two vectors of dimensions n, and then prints a sum of loaded vector. The calculation of the sum of two vectors should be performed in a recursive function whose prototype is:

```
 void saberi(double *vector_a,double *vector_b,double *vector_res,int n)
```

I did it until the part when the recursion should be done, I don't know how to do it, so any help would be welcome.

My code now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100

void sum(double *vector_a,double *vector_b,double *vector_res,int n)
{

}
int main()
{
   int n;
   int sum;
   double a[MAX],b[MAX],c[MAX];
   printf("Insert dimension of vector (n):\n");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   printf("Insert a element of vector a:\n");
   int i;
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   {
     scanf("%d",a[i]);
   }
   printf("Insert a element of vector b:\n");
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   {
       scanf("%d",b[i]);
   }
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   {
       result=sum(a,b,result,n);
   }
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   {
       printf("%d",result);
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance !
Best regards :)

Comment: This is a pure example of a stupid artificial problem, created by teachers who do not undestand the power of recursion. This way they teach applying recursion artificially to problems, which are far easier, simpler and more effectively solved by iteration. As a result they create programmers who believe a recursion is a stupid, artificial method of writing ineffective programs hard way instead of easy writing simple iterative programs. Arrrrgh....!

Comment: @CiaPan bravo!!!

Comment: Yes, I also agree with your comment, I know how to solve it by iteration, but it is not a problem, but the task states that recursion is used.

Comment: So I have shown how  to do it with recursion, haven't I...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *agree* with CiaPan's comment [a *bad* use of recursion].

But, given lemons, we can make lemonade.

There's some old maxims [from "Elements of Programming Style" by Kernighan and Plauger]:

1. Make it right before you make it faster
2. Keep it right when you make it faster
3. Make it clear before you make it faster

So, we should create the simpler iterative solution *first*. We can then use that as a cross check against the new, "faster" version [in our case here, the recursive solution].

So, we can make a diagnostic test suite/program to compare results [see below].

This technique is a good one to use, in general, whenever we have *working* code but the code is too slow and we need a faster version. Or, the code is cumbersome and should be refactored to be simpler/clearer/cleaner.

Also, if we're trying to make the code *faster*, we should *measure* the speed of the original code and the "faster" code to be sure that we actually made the code faster [and, not, ironically *slower*].

---

First there were a number of bugs:

Iterating over `i = 1;  i <= n;  ++i` instead of `i = 0;  i < n;  ++i`. This causes UB [undefined behavior] because we're *not* changing element 0 and going beyond the end of an array.

The `scanf` were wrong because we want `%lf` and *not* `%d`. And, we want: `&vector_a[i]` and *not* `vector_a[i]`. If we had compiled with `-Wall` these would have been flagged by the compiler.

The `sum` function was trying to return an address from a `void` function.

It was being called in a loop, but the function itself should do the loop.

Here's an annotated version.

I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old code vs new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif
```

Anyway, here is that code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100

void
sum(double *vector_a, double *vector_b, double *vector_rez, int n)
{
#if 0
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return vector_res = vector_a + vector_b;
#else
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < n;  ++idx)
        vector_rez[idx] = vector_a[idx] + vector_b[idx];
#endif
}

int
main()
{
    int n;
#if 0
    int result;
#endif
    double vector_a[MAX];
    double vector_b[MAX];
// NOTE/BUG: the code below uses vector_res and _not_ vector_rez
#if 0
    double vector_rez[MAX];
#else
    double vector_res[MAX];
#endif

    printf("Insert dimension of vector (n):\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int i;

// NOTE/BUG: vectors start at index 0 and _not_ 1 -- this is an issue for _all_
// for loops below

// NOTE/BUG: we want "%lf" and _not_ "%d"
// NOTE/BUG: we want (e.g.) &vector_a[i] (a pointer to the element) and _not_
// vector_a[i] (the value of the vector element)
#if 0
    printf("Insert element of vector a:\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", vector_a[i]);
    }
    printf("Insert element of vector b:\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", vector_b[i]);
    }
#else
    printf("Insert element of vector a:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%lf", &vector_a[i]);
    }
    printf("Insert element of vector b:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%lf", &vector_b[i]);
    }
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: we want the loop to be in the sum function and _not_ here
// otherwise, why pass down vector_res
#if 0
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        vector_res[i] = sum(vector_a, vector_b, vector_res, n);
    }
#else
    sum(vector_a,vector_b,vector_res,n);
#endif

#if 0
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        printf("%d", vector_res[i]);
    }
#else
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf(" %f\n", vector_res[i]);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's a refactored version that implements both an iterative function and a recursive function.

Note that the iterative version (`sumiter`) iterates from 0 to `n - 1` [which is cache friendly].

But, for the recursive version (`sumcall`) we *can't* do that. We'd need an extra argument that is the current index [in addition to the `n` argument].

So, we have to sum from `n - 1` to 0.

Here's a version that runs tests and compares both functions for correctness and aborts if the recursive function doesn't match the iterative one (i.e. we're applying the above maxims):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX 100

// sumiter -- sum vectors [iterative]
void
sumiter(double *vector_a, double *vector_b, double *vector_rez, int n)
{
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < n;  ++idx)
        vector_rez[idx] = vector_a[idx] + vector_b[idx];
}

// sumcall -- sum vectors [recursive]
void
sumcall(double *vector_a, double *vector_b, double *vector_rez, int idx)
{

    --idx;
    if (idx < 0)
        return;

    vector_rez[idx] = vector_a[idx] + vector_b[idx];

    sumcall(vector_a,vector_b,vector_rez,idx);
}

void
randvec(double *vec,int n)
{

    for (int idx = 0;  idx < n;  ++idx)
        vec[idx] = drand48();
}

double
tscgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);
    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    return sec;
}

double
dofnc(void (*fnc)(double *a, double *b, double *rez, int n),
    double *a,double *b,double *res,int n)
{
    double elap_best = 1e9;

    for (int iter = 1;  iter <= 5;  ++iter) {
        double elap_beg = tscgetf();

        fnc(a,b,res,n);

        double elap_end = tscgetf();
        elap_end -= elap_beg;

        if (elap_end < elap_best)
            elap_best = elap_end;
    }

    return elap_best;
}

void
dotest(int n)
{
    double vector_a[MAX];
    double vector_b[MAX];
    double res_iter[MAX];
    double res_call[MAX];
    int stopflg = 0;

    if (n > MAX)
        n = MAX;

    randvec(vector_a,n);
    randvec(vector_b,n);

    double elap_iter = dofnc(sumiter,vector_a,vector_b,res_iter,n);
    double elap_call = dofnc(sumcall,vector_a,vector_b,res_call,n);

    // show elapsed time
    printf("ITER: %.9f\n",elap_iter);
    printf("CALL: %.9f\n",elap_call);

    for (int idx = 0;  idx < n;  ++idx) {
        int miss = (res_call[idx] != res_iter[idx]);
        if (miss)
            stopflg = 1;
        printf("dotest: %d %f %f%s\n",
            idx,res_iter[idx],res_call[idx],miss ? " (FAIL)" : "");
    }

    printf("dotest: %s\n",stopflg ? "FAIL" : "PASS");

    if (stopflg)
        exit(1);
}

int
main(void)
{

    dotest(20);
    dotest(67);
    dotest(MAX);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the program output:

```
ITER: 0.000000042
CALL: 0.000000043
dotest: 0 0.875981 0.875981
dotest: 1 0.532542 0.532542
dotest: 2 0.961892 0.961892
dotest: 3 0.692074 0.692074
dotest: 4 1.175032 1.175032
dotest: 5 0.279751 0.279751
dotest: 6 0.978612 0.978612
dotest: 7 1.057831 1.057831
dotest: 8 0.603525 0.603525
dotest: 9 1.269707 1.269707
dotest: 10 1.218069 1.218069
dotest: 11 0.949643 0.949643
dotest: 12 1.825637 1.825637
dotest: 13 1.352543 1.352543
dotest: 14 0.657011 0.657011
dotest: 15 0.304143 0.304143
dotest: 16 0.786893 0.786893
dotest: 17 0.397292 0.397292
dotest: 18 0.931237 0.931237
dotest: 19 0.979120 0.979120
dotest: PASS
ITER: 0.000000101
CALL: 0.000000100
dotest: 0 1.481146 1.481146
dotest: 1 0.972322 0.972322
dotest: 2 1.381247 1.381247
dotest: 3 0.592519 0.592519
dotest: 4 1.486516 1.486516
dotest: 5 0.904968 0.904968
dotest: 6 1.032588 1.032588
dotest: 7 0.514809 0.514809
dotest: 8 1.450355 1.450355
dotest: 9 0.986021 0.986021
dotest: 10 1.501674 1.501674
dotest: 11 0.510463 0.510463
dotest: 12 1.486773 1.486773
dotest: 13 1.279277 1.279277
dotest: 14 1.299667 1.299667
dotest: 15 0.793899 0.793899
dotest: 16 1.487031 1.487031
dotest: 17 1.552800 1.552800
dotest: 18 0.616313 0.616313
dotest: 19 0.993808 0.993808
dotest: 20 1.286723 1.286723
dotest: 21 1.249075 1.249075
dotest: 22 0.083708 0.083708
dotest: 23 1.575160 1.575160
dotest: 24 1.126545 1.126545
dotest: 25 0.264593 0.264593
dotest: 26 0.795436 0.795436
dotest: 27 0.973021 0.973021
dotest: 28 0.985016 0.985016
dotest: 29 1.752784 1.752784
dotest: 30 0.852236 0.852236
dotest: 31 1.499697 1.499697
dotest: 32 1.423587 1.423587
dotest: 33 0.924229 0.924229
dotest: 34 1.271571 1.271571
dotest: 35 1.573766 1.573766
dotest: 36 1.548978 1.548978
dotest: 37 1.732789 1.732789
dotest: 38 1.085471 1.085471
dotest: 39 0.483692 0.483692
dotest: 40 1.030894 1.030894
dotest: 41 0.286513 0.286513
dotest: 42 0.872451 0.872451
dotest: 43 1.230225 1.230225
dotest: 44 1.251257 1.251257
dotest: 45 1.282516 1.282516
dotest: 46 0.557632 0.557632
dotest: 47 0.824636 0.824636
dotest: 48 0.507834 0.507834
dotest: 49 0.303870 0.303870
dotest: 50 0.021515 0.021515
dotest: 51 0.431755 0.431755
dotest: 52 0.623890 0.623890
dotest: 53 0.596018 0.596018
dotest: 54 0.552220 0.552220
dotest: 55 0.959291 0.959291
dotest: 56 1.667865 1.667865
dotest: 57 1.216065 1.216065
dotest: 58 0.346906 0.346906
dotest: 59 0.973154 0.973154
dotest: 60 1.073773 1.073773
dotest: 61 1.070332 1.070332
dotest: 62 0.723126 0.723126
dotest: 63 1.371606 1.371606
dotest: 64 1.053194 1.053194
dotest: 65 0.266924 0.266924
dotest: 66 1.266108 1.266108
dotest: PASS
ITER: 0.000000135
CALL: 0.000000134
dotest: 0 1.224731 1.224731
dotest: 1 1.549801 1.549801
dotest: 2 0.210620 0.210620
dotest: 3 1.821897 1.821897
dotest: 4 0.239412 0.239412
dotest: 5 0.245666 0.245666
dotest: 6 0.306005 0.306005
dotest: 7 0.435580 0.435580
dotest: 8 1.439958 1.439958
dotest: 9 1.330953 1.330953
dotest: 10 0.962920 0.962920
dotest: 11 1.129370 1.129370
dotest: 12 0.979000 0.979000
dotest: 13 1.271833 1.271833
dotest: 14 1.180285 1.180285
dotest: 15 1.115377 1.115377
dotest: 16 1.379975 1.379975
dotest: 17 1.083476 1.083476
dotest: 18 0.916506 0.916506
dotest: 19 0.521584 0.521584
dotest: 20 1.725734 1.725734
dotest: 21 1.514879 1.514879
dotest: 22 0.513368 0.513368
dotest: 23 0.696086 0.696086
dotest: 24 0.969453 0.969453
dotest: 25 0.540273 0.540273
dotest: 26 1.479472 1.479472
dotest: 27 0.222709 0.222709
dotest: 28 0.334622 0.334622
dotest: 29 0.878528 0.878528
dotest: 30 1.122719 1.122719
dotest: 31 1.244526 1.244526
dotest: 32 1.394182 1.394182
dotest: 33 1.225557 1.225557
dotest: 34 1.530945 1.530945
dotest: 35 1.604853 1.604853
dotest: 36 0.895270 0.895270
dotest: 37 1.279060 1.279060
dotest: 38 0.052540 0.052540
dotest: 39 0.273471 0.273471
dotest: 40 0.969764 0.969764
dotest: 41 1.071431 1.071431
dotest: 42 0.359576 0.359576
dotest: 43 0.718445 0.718445
dotest: 44 1.692190 1.692190
dotest: 45 1.497816 1.497816
dotest: 46 0.675670 0.675670
dotest: 47 1.031740 1.031740
dotest: 48 0.572276 0.572276
dotest: 49 0.905983 0.905983
dotest: 50 0.266687 0.266687
dotest: 51 0.471825 0.471825
dotest: 52 0.462346 0.462346
dotest: 53 1.157948 1.157948
dotest: 54 0.928059 0.928059
dotest: 55 0.931817 0.931817
dotest: 56 1.389035 1.389035
dotest: 57 1.416517 1.416517
dotest: 58 1.217675 1.217675
dotest: 59 0.991833 0.991833
dotest: 60 1.259813 1.259813
dotest: 61 0.070612 0.070612
dotest: 62 0.493996 0.493996
dotest: 63 0.514937 0.514937
dotest: 64 1.429208 1.429208
dotest: 65 1.490289 1.490289
dotest: 66 1.497546 1.497546
dotest: 67 1.074150 1.074150
dotest: 68 1.325306 1.325306
dotest: 69 0.775838 0.775838
dotest: 70 0.988785 0.988785
dotest: 71 1.261825 1.261825
dotest: 72 0.228171 0.228171
dotest: 73 0.196502 0.196502
dotest: 74 0.711210 0.711210
dotest: 75 0.571607 0.571607
dotest: 76 1.758753 1.758753
dotest: 77 0.745936 0.745936
dotest: 78 1.226576 1.226576
dotest: 79 1.027937 1.027937
dotest: 80 1.486168 1.486168
dotest: 81 1.097114 1.097114
dotest: 82 0.666452 0.666452
dotest: 83 1.070599 1.070599
dotest: 84 0.505941 0.505941
dotest: 85 1.424329 1.424329
dotest: 86 1.514565 1.514565
dotest: 87 0.915301 0.915301
dotest: 88 1.000928 1.000928
dotest: 89 1.060346 1.060346
dotest: 90 1.687241 1.687241
dotest: 91 0.270245 0.270245
dotest: 92 1.195685 1.195685
dotest: 93 1.040315 1.040315
dotest: 94 0.580820 0.580820
dotest: 95 0.988709 0.988709
dotest: 96 0.185577 0.185577
dotest: 97 1.299616 1.299616
dotest: 98 1.727305 1.727305
dotest: 99 0.105829 0.105829
dotest: PASS
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> If you do addition after the recursive call, as I proposed in a pseudocode, the operation on vectors would go upwards, that is in a cache-friendly direction. However, the call stack management cost is likely to mask the difference.

Well, let's test that ...

I've enhanced the test so that it can compare many different functions with much larger vectors.

I've added your test [what I *think* is your test].

I've added the program output below.

Actually, you may be not be happy with the results. My comment below was before I double checked the benchmark results [and added stack expansion].

Strangely, as I've coded your solution it is 8x *slower* than my recursive solution. I may have coded it wrong, but it seems to compare okay.

My recursive solution was faster than the iterative one, which was strange. Turns out that was for `-O2`. With `-O3`, the iterative solution is fastest.

---

Here's the updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

#define MAX     1000000

int opt_v;

// sumiter -- sum vectors [iterative]
void
sumiter(double *vector_a, double *vector_b, double *vector_rez, int n)
{
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < n;  ++idx)
        vector_rez[idx] = vector_a[idx] + vector_b[idx];
}

// sumcall -- sum vectors [recursive]
void
sumcall(double *vector_a, double *vector_b, double *vector_rez, int idx)
{

    --idx;
    if (idx < 0)
        return;

    vector_rez[idx] = vector_a[idx] + vector_b[idx];

    sumcall(vector_a,vector_b,vector_rez,idx);
}

// sumcia -- sum vectors [CiaPan's algorithm]
void
sumcia(double *vector_a, double *vector_b, double *vector_rez, int idx)
{

    --idx;
    if (idx < 0)
        return;

    sumcia(vector_a,vector_b,vector_rez,idx);

    vector_rez[idx] = vector_a[idx] + vector_b[idx];
}

typedef struct {
    void (*fnc_fnc)(double *a, double *b, double *rez, int n);
    const char *fnc_sym;
    double fnc_elap;
    int fnc_best;
} fnc_t;

#define DOFNC(_fnc) \
    { .fnc_fnc = _fnc, .fnc_sym = #_fnc }

fnc_t fnclist[] = {
    DOFNC(sumiter),
    DOFNC(sumcall),
    DOFNC(sumcia),
    { .fnc_fnc = NULL }
};

void *
xmalloc(size_t len)
{
    void *ptr;

    ptr = malloc(len);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        perror("xmalloc");
        exit(1);
    }

    return ptr;
}

double *
randvec(int n)
{
    double *vec;

    vec = xmalloc(sizeof(*vec) * n);

    for (int idx = 0;  idx < n;  ++idx)
        vec[idx] = drand48();

    return vec;
}

double
tscgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);
    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    return sec;
}

void
dofnc(fnc_t *fnc,double *a,double *b,double *res,int n)
{
    double elap_best = 1e9;

    for (int iter = 1;  iter <= 5;  ++iter) {
        double elap_beg = tscgetf();

        fnc->fnc_fnc(a,b,res,n);

        double elap_end = tscgetf();
        elap_end -= elap_beg;

        if (elap_end < elap_best)
            elap_best = elap_end;
    }

    printf("ELAPSED: %.9f (%s)\n",elap_best,fnc->fnc_sym);

    fnc->fnc_elap = elap_best;
}

void
dotest(int n)
{
    int stopflg = 0;

    printf("\n");

    n = (rand() % n) + 1;
    printf("dotest: N %d\n",n);

    double *vector_a = randvec(n);
    double *vector_b = randvec(n);

    double *res_cur = xmalloc(sizeof(*res_cur) * n);
    double *res_old = xmalloc(sizeof(*res_old) * n);

    int cmpflg = 0;
    for (fnc_t *fnc = fnclist;  fnc->fnc_fnc != NULL;  ++fnc, cmpflg = 1) {
        for (int idx = 0;  idx < n;  ++idx)
            res_cur[idx] = 0;

        dofnc(fnc,vector_a,vector_b,res_cur,n);

        if (cmpflg) {
            for (int idx = 0;  idx < n;  ++idx) {
                int miss = (res_cur[idx] != res_old[idx]);
                if (miss)
                    stopflg = 1;
                if (miss || opt_v)
                    printf("dotest: %d %f %f%s\n",
                        idx,res_cur[idx],res_old[idx],miss ? " (FAIL)" : "");
            }

            if (stopflg || opt_v)
                printf("dotest: %s\n",stopflg ? "FAIL" : "PASS");
        }

        if (stopflg)
            exit(1);

        double *tmp = res_cur;
        res_cur = res_old;
        res_old = tmp;
    }

    fnc_t *best = fnclist;
    for (fnc_t *fnc = fnclist;  fnc->fnc_fnc != NULL;  ++fnc) {
        if (fnc->fnc_elap < best->fnc_elap)
            best = fnc;
    }
    best->fnc_best += 1;
    printf("BEST: %s (%d times)\n",best->fnc_sym,best->fnc_best);
    fflush(stdout);

    free(vector_a);
    free(vector_b);
    free(res_cur);
    free(res_old);
}

void *
testall(void *ptr)
{

    dotest(20);
    dotest(67);
    for (int tstno = 1;  tstno <= 20;  ++tstno)
        dotest(MAX);

    return (void *) 0;
}

int
bigstack(void)
{
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    // allocate a 256MB region for the stack.
    size_t stacksize = 3LL * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr, stacksize);

    int rc = pthread_create(&thread, &attr, testall, NULL);

    if (rc) {
        printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
        return 0;
    }

    pthread_join(thread, NULL);

    return 1;
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 'v':
            opt_v = ! opt_v;
            break;
        }
    }

    bigstack();

    return 0;
}
```

---

And, here is the output with `-O2`:

```
dotest: N 4
ELAPSED: 0.000000033 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.000000032 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.000000044 (sumcia)
BEST: sumcall (1 times)

dotest: N 34
ELAPSED: 0.000000062 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.000000056 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.000000188 (sumcia)
BEST: sumcall (2 times)

dotest: N 692778
ELAPSED: 0.002301515 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.002376126 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.012824440 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (1 times)

dotest: N 636916
ELAPSED: 0.001993325 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.002052745 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.011495179 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (2 times)

dotest: N 747794
ELAPSED: 0.002486300 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.002439044 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.013481327 (sumcia)
BEST: sumcall (3 times)

dotest: N 238336
ELAPSED: 0.000443464 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.000381538 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.003709807 (sumcia)
BEST: sumcall (4 times)

dotest: N 885387
ELAPSED: 0.002856842 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.002943572 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.022802362 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (3 times)

dotest: N 760493
ELAPSED: 0.005853769 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.004284444 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.016364582 (sumcia)
BEST: sumcall (5 times)

dotest: N 516650
ELAPSED: 0.001944555 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.001976967 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.009940383 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (4 times)

dotest: N 641422
ELAPSED: 0.002302542 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.002202840 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.011445785 (sumcia)
BEST: sumcall (6 times)

dotest: N 202363
ELAPSED: 0.000285884 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.000311852 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.003159435 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (5 times)

dotest: N 490028
ELAPSED: 0.001514360 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.001466043 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.008706644 (sumcia)
BEST: sumcall (7 times)

dotest: N 368691
ELAPSED: 0.001025306 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.000961459 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.006162354 (sumcia)
BEST: sumcall (8 times)

dotest: N 520060
ELAPSED: 0.001497262 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.001586368 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.009255096 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (6 times)

dotest: N 897764
ELAPSED: 0.002939831 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.002881219 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.016707118 (sumcia)
BEST: sumcall (9 times)

dotest: N 513927
ELAPSED: 0.001416308 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.001367614 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.009001773 (sumcia)
BEST: sumcall (10 times)

dotest: N 180541
ELAPSED: 0.000243008 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.000239538 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.002559435 (sumcia)
BEST: sumcall (11 times)

dotest: N 383427
ELAPSED: 0.000952569 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.000931755 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.006504057 (sumcia)
BEST: sumcall (12 times)

dotest: N 89173
ELAPSED: 0.000118174 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.000116643 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.000757717 (sumcia)
BEST: sumcall (13 times)

dotest: N 455737
ELAPSED: 0.001378270 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.001315465 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.007850135 (sumcia)
BEST: sumcall (14 times)

dotest: N 5212
ELAPSED: 0.000005663 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.000005643 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.000032479 (sumcia)
BEST: sumcall (15 times)

dotest: N 595369
ELAPSED: 0.001752237 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.001727643 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.010160110 (sumcia)
BEST: sumcall (16 times)
```

However, here is the output with `-O3`:

```
dotest: N 4
ELAPSED: 0.000000061 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.000000058 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.000000077 (sumcia)
BEST: sumcall (1 times)

dotest: N 34
ELAPSED: 0.000000066 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.000000104 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.000000301 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (1 times)

dotest: N 692778
ELAPSED: 0.002209531 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.002396807 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.012517166 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (2 times)

dotest: N 636916
ELAPSED: 0.001690255 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.001920715 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.011362423 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (3 times)

dotest: N 747794
ELAPSED: 0.002070943 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.002294327 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.013792094 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (4 times)

dotest: N 238336
ELAPSED: 0.000358729 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.000354468 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.003499538 (sumcia)
BEST: sumcall (2 times)

dotest: N 885387
ELAPSED: 0.004246246 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.004364282 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.024312321 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (5 times)

dotest: N 760493
ELAPSED: 0.002452109 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.003049928 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.013849192 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (6 times)

dotest: N 516650
ELAPSED: 0.001331265 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.001387272 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.009053577 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (7 times)

dotest: N 641422
ELAPSED: 0.001681784 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.001777012 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.011311826 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (8 times)

dotest: N 202363
ELAPSED: 0.000244712 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.000315439 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.002864857 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (9 times)

dotest: N 490028
ELAPSED: 0.001249077 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.001322027 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.008425179 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (10 times)

dotest: N 368691
ELAPSED: 0.001146392 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.000941854 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.005957630 (sumcia)
BEST: sumcall (3 times)

dotest: N 520060
ELAPSED: 0.001347512 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.001452342 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.008846269 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (11 times)

dotest: N 897764
ELAPSED: 0.002495836 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.002817348 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.021163486 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (12 times)

dotest: N 513927
ELAPSED: 0.003603522 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.003335355 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.010755654 (sumcia)
BEST: sumcall (4 times)

dotest: N 180541
ELAPSED: 0.000270910 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.000308384 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.003348084 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (13 times)

dotest: N 383427
ELAPSED: 0.001215342 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.001520112 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.008144502 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (14 times)

dotest: N 89173
ELAPSED: 0.000108698 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.000133748 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.000855184 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (15 times)

dotest: N 455737
ELAPSED: 0.001418886 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.001442705 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.008022073 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (16 times)

dotest: N 5212
ELAPSED: 0.000003999 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.000004181 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.000037246 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (17 times)

dotest: N 595369
ELAPSED: 0.001566719 (sumiter)
ELAPSED: 0.001623171 (sumcall)
ELAPSED: 0.010692337 (sumcia)
BEST: sumiter (18 times)
```

Comment: If you do addition _after_ the recursive call, as I proposed in a pseudocode, the operation on vectors would go upwards, that is in a cache-friendly direction. However, the call stack management cost is likely to mask the difference.

Comment: @CiaPan I've created a version with your algorithm in it. You might be [pleasantly] surprised.

Comment: When I looked at the results from the first phase of your tests I noticed a surprising similarity of values obtained for `sumiter` and `sumcall` – their relative difference is about 1 .. 2%. Too small, I feel. Possibly the compiler improved your `sumcall` code? Please notice you have a tail recursion there, so it is eligible for automatic transformation into a simple `while` loop. Additionally, all parameters except `idx` are passed unchanged and `idx` is just simply decremented. I suppose a modern compiler can make a simple `for()` from it.

Comment: (contd.) On the other hand `sumcia` does some calculations after the return from recursion, hence a stack management overhead is unavoidable and it shows up in the results.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose elements 0 through n–1 can be added *somehow* – so you just need to add `a[n] + b[n]` and put the result to `c[n]`, right?

The base case would be adding zero-items vectors, which is an empty operation.

So the solution would go like this:

```
to sum vectors a and b to c with length n:
    if n > 0 then
        sum vectors a and b to c with length (n-1)
        set item c[n] to a sum of a[n] and b[n]
    done
```